# Swift 3 sending a custom `Error` via `Notification` cannot be cast to `Error` in the observing method

Tags: swift, swift3, casting

I have a custom error enum:

```
enum MyError: LocalizedError {
    case runtimeError(String)

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .runtimeError(let message):
            return message
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send this `MyError` via `NotificationCenter` as the object of `Notification` e.g.:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .errorMessage, object: MyError.runtimeError("Some error message"))
```

The problem is when it arrives into my method, casting the object to `Error` fails i.e. returns `nil`:

```
@objc private func errorMessage(notification: Notification) {
    guard let error = notification.object as? Error else {
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

I played in the debugger with casting the object and it can be cast to `MyError` and then it can be downcasted to `Error` i.e. this is non-nil `(notification.object as? MyError) as? Error`.

When I used a `struct` instead of an `enum` for `MyError` it behaves the same (i.e. cast to `Error` is `nil`), but using a `class` works perfectly. Is this a bug in Swift language or am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect this is because MyError needs to derive from NSObject (i.e. `@objc`) in order to passed as the object of a `Notification`, which would rule out native Swift `enum` and `struct`. I can't easily google up the proof, though.

Comment: Does it work if you pass `object: MyError.runtimeError("Some error message") as NSError` instead?

Comment: @MartinR that fixed the problem but casting `MyError` in all such situations is error prone and I prefer @CharlesSrstka's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically due to BS in the Swift<->Objective-C bridging magic. If you check the dynamic type on the value returned by `notification.object`, you'll see it's not actually your error type, but rather an opaque type called `_SwiftValue` that is used to wrap Swift value types for Objective-C APIs which only take classes. This can throw a spanner into the works sometimes, for reasons that don't always appear to make sense.

Anyway, this'll fix it:

```
guard let error = notification.object as AnyObject as? Error else {
    return
}
```

EDIT: You're probably wondering why on earth this matters. Well, I'm not going to claim to be an absolute authority. But I can look at the disassembly to try to figure out what on earth the compiler is doing. And this is what I see:

For

```
func foo(_ notification: Notification) {
    let error = notification.object as? Error
}
```

I get:

```
totalbs`foo(_:):
    0x100002550 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x100002551 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100002554 <+4>:   subq   $0xb0, %rsp
    0x10000255b <+11>:  leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000255f <+15>:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
->  0x100002563 <+19>:  movq   %rdi, %rcx
    0x100002566 <+22>:  addq   $0x8, %rcx
    0x10000256a <+26>:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
    0x10000256d <+29>:  testb  $0x1, 0x28(%rdi)
    0x100002571 <+33>:  movq   %rdi, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x100002575 <+37>:  movq   %rcx, -0x50(%rbp)
    0x100002579 <+41>:  movq   %rax, -0x58(%rbp)
    0x10000257d <+45>:  movq   %rdx, -0x60(%rbp)
    0x100002581 <+49>:  jne    0x1000025b5               ; <+101> at main.swift
    0x100002583 <+51>:  movq   -0x60(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002587 <+55>:  movq   0x18(%rax), %rcx
    0x10000258b <+59>:  movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rdx
    0x10000258f <+63>:  movq   %rcx, 0x18(%rdx)
    0x100002593 <+67>:  movq   -0x8(%rcx), %rsi
    0x100002597 <+71>:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
    0x10000259a <+74>:  movq   %rsi, -0x68(%rbp)
    0x10000259e <+78>:  movq   %rax, %rsi
    0x1000025a1 <+81>:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
    0x1000025a4 <+84>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1000025a8 <+88>:  callq  *0x8(%rcx)
    0x1000025ab <+91>:  movb   $0x0, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1000025af <+95>:  movq   %rax, -0x70(%rbp)
    0x1000025b3 <+99>:  jmp    0x1000025cc               ; <+124> at main.swift:17
    0x1000025b5 <+101>: movl   $0x21, %eax
    0x1000025ba <+106>: movl   %eax, %edx
    0x1000025bc <+108>: leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1000025c0 <+112>: movq   -0x50(%rbp), %rsi
    0x1000025c4 <+116>: movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x1000025c7 <+119>: callq  0x10051b18c               ; symbol stub for: memcpy
    0x1000025cc <+124>: movb   -0x10(%rbp), %al
    0x1000025cf <+127>: xorb   $-0x1, %al
    0x1000025d1 <+129>: testb  $0x1, %al
    0x1000025d3 <+131>: jne    0x1000025ec               ; <+156> at main.swift
    0x1000025d5 <+133>: testb  $0x1, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1000025d9 <+137>: jne    0x1000025e7               ; <+151> at main.swift:17
    0x1000025db <+139>: leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000025df <+143>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1000025e2 <+146>: callq  0x1000029c0               ; __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 at main.swift
    0x1000025e7 <+151>: jmp    0x1000026d0               ; <+384> at main.swift
    0x1000025ec <+156>: leaq   -0x40(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000025f0 <+160>: leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1000025f4 <+164>: movq   %rax, -0x78(%rbp)
    0x1000025f8 <+168>: movq   %rcx, -0x80(%rbp)
    0x1000025fc <+172>: callq  0x100002a80               ; type metadata accessor for Any at main.swift
    0x100002601 <+177>: movq   %rax, -0x88(%rbp)
    0x100002608 <+184>: callq  0x100002b00               ; type metadata accessor for Swift.Error at main.swift
    0x10000260d <+189>: movl   $0x6, %edx
    0x100002612 <+194>: movl   %edx, %r8d
    0x100002615 <+197>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100002619 <+201>: movq   -0x80(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10000261d <+205>: movq   -0x88(%rbp), %rdx
    0x100002624 <+212>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x100002627 <+215>: callq  0x100002b60               ; swift_rt_swift_dynamicCast
    0x10000262c <+220>: testb  $0x1, %al
    0x10000262e <+222>: jne    0x100002632               ; <+226> at main.swift:17
    0x100002630 <+224>: jmp    0x10000263f               ; <+239> at main.swift
    0x100002632 <+226>: movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002636 <+230>: movq   %rax, -0x90(%rbp)
    0x10000263d <+237>: jmp    0x10000264a               ; <+250> at main.swift:17
    0x10000263f <+239>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x100002641 <+241>: movl   %eax, %ecx
    0x100002643 <+243>: movq   %rcx, -0x90(%rbp)
    0x10000264a <+250>: movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002651 <+257>: movq   %rax, -0x98(%rbp)
    0x100002658 <+264>: movq   -0x98(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000265f <+271>: movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x100002663 <+275>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100002666 <+278>: callq  0x100509080               ; swift_errorRelease
    0x10000266b <+283>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000266f <+287>: movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x100002672 <+290>: callq  0x10051b20a               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x100002677 <+295>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000267b <+299>: addq   $0x8, %rax
    0x10000267f <+303>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100002683 <+307>: testb  $0x1, 0x28(%rdi)
    0x100002687 <+311>: movq   %rax, -0xa0(%rbp)
    0x10000268e <+318>: jne    0x10000269f               ; <+335> at main.swift:18
    0x100002690 <+320>: movq   -0xa0(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002697 <+327>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10000269a <+330>: callq  0x1000029c0               ; __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 at main.swift
    0x10000269f <+335>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000026a3 <+339>: addq   $0x30, %rax
    0x1000026a7 <+343>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1000026ab <+347>: testb  $0x1, 0x38(%rcx)
    0x1000026af <+351>: movq   %rax, -0xa8(%rbp)
    0x1000026b6 <+358>: jne    0x1000026c7               ; <+375> at main.swift:18
    0x1000026b8 <+360>: movq   -0xa8(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000026bf <+367>: movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x1000026c2 <+370>: callq  0x100001bb0               ; outlined copy of Swift._VariantDictionaryBuffer with unmangled suffix ".1"
    0x1000026c7 <+375>: addq   $0xb0, %rsp
    0x1000026ce <+382>: popq   %rbp
    0x1000026cf <+383>: retq   
    0x1000026d0 <+384>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x1000026d2 <+386>: movl   %eax, %ecx
    0x1000026d4 <+388>: movq   %rcx, -0x98(%rbp)
    0x1000026db <+395>: jmp    0x100002658               ; <+264> at main.swift
```

Whereas for

```
func foo(_ notification: Notification) {
    let error = notification.object as AnyObject as? Error
}
```

I get:

```
totalbs`foo(_:):
    0x1000024e0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x1000024e1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1000024e4 <+4>:   pushq  %r13
    0x1000024e6 <+6>:   subq   $0xb8, %rsp
    0x1000024ed <+13>:  leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000024f1 <+17>:  movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
->  0x1000024f5 <+21>:  movq   %rdi, %rcx
    0x1000024f8 <+24>:  addq   $0x8, %rcx
    0x1000024fc <+28>:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
    0x1000024ff <+31>:  testb  $0x1, 0x28(%rdi)
    0x100002503 <+35>:  movq   %rdi, -0x58(%rbp)
    0x100002507 <+39>:  movq   %rcx, -0x60(%rbp)
    0x10000250b <+43>:  movq   %rax, -0x68(%rbp)
    0x10000250f <+47>:  movq   %rdx, -0x70(%rbp)
    0x100002513 <+51>:  jne    0x100002547               ; <+103> at main.swift
    0x100002515 <+53>:  movq   -0x70(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002519 <+57>:  movq   0x18(%rax), %rcx
    0x10000251d <+61>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rdx
    0x100002521 <+65>:  movq   %rcx, 0x18(%rdx)
    0x100002525 <+69>:  movq   -0x8(%rcx), %rsi
    0x100002529 <+73>:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
    0x10000252c <+76>:  movq   %rsi, -0x78(%rbp)
    0x100002530 <+80>:  movq   %rax, %rsi
    0x100002533 <+83>:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
    0x100002536 <+86>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10000253a <+90>:  callq  *0x8(%rcx)
    0x10000253d <+93>:  movb   $0x0, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x100002541 <+97>:  movq   %rax, -0x80(%rbp)
    0x100002545 <+101>: jmp    0x10000255e               ; <+126> at main.swift:17
    0x100002547 <+103>: movl   $0x21, %eax
    0x10000254c <+108>: movl   %eax, %edx
    0x10000254e <+110>: leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100002552 <+114>: movq   -0x60(%rbp), %rsi
    0x100002556 <+118>: movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x100002559 <+121>: callq  0x10051b18c               ; symbol stub for: memcpy
    0x10000255e <+126>: callq  0x100002a20               ; type metadata accessor for Swift.Optional<Any> at main.swift
    0x100002563 <+131>: leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100002567 <+135>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10000256a <+138>: movq   %rcx, %r13
    0x10000256d <+141>: callq  0x10029cfe0               ; Swift.Optional._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> Swift.AnyObject
    0x100002572 <+146>: testb  $0x1, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x100002576 <+150>: movq   %rax, -0x88(%rbp)
    0x10000257d <+157>: jne    0x10000258b               ; <+171> at main.swift
    0x10000257f <+159>: leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002583 <+163>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100002586 <+166>: callq  0x100002960               ; __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 at main.swift
    0x10000258b <+171>: leaq   -0x40(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000258f <+175>: leaq   -0x48(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100002593 <+179>: movq   -0x88(%rbp), %rdx
    0x10000259a <+186>: movq   %rdx, -0x40(%rbp)
    0x10000259e <+190>: movq   %rcx, -0x90(%rbp)
    0x1000025a5 <+197>: movq   %rax, -0x98(%rbp)
    0x1000025ac <+204>: callq  0x100002ae0               ; type metadata accessor for Swift.AnyObject at main.swift
    0x1000025b1 <+209>: movq   %rax, -0xa0(%rbp)
    0x1000025b8 <+216>: callq  0x100002b30               ; type metadata accessor for Swift.Error at main.swift
    0x1000025bd <+221>: movl   $0x6, %esi
    0x1000025c2 <+226>: movl   %esi, %r8d
    0x1000025c5 <+229>: movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x1000025cc <+236>: movq   -0x98(%rbp), %rsi
    0x1000025d3 <+243>: movq   -0xa0(%rbp), %rdx
    0x1000025da <+250>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x1000025dd <+253>: callq  0x100002b90               ; swift_rt_swift_dynamicCast
    0x1000025e2 <+258>: testb  $0x1, %al
    0x1000025e4 <+260>: jne    0x1000025e8               ; <+264> at main.swift:17
    0x1000025e6 <+262>: jmp    0x1000025f5               ; <+277> at main.swift
    0x1000025e8 <+264>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000025ec <+268>: movq   %rax, -0xa8(%rbp)
    0x1000025f3 <+275>: jmp    0x100002600               ; <+288> at main.swift
    0x1000025f5 <+277>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x1000025f7 <+279>: movl   %eax, %ecx
    0x1000025f9 <+281>: movq   %rcx, -0xa8(%rbp)
    0x100002600 <+288>: movq   -0xa8(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002607 <+295>: movq   %rax, -0x50(%rbp)
    0x10000260b <+299>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10000260e <+302>: callq  0x100509080               ; swift_errorRelease
    0x100002613 <+307>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002617 <+311>: movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x10000261a <+314>: callq  0x10051b20a               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10000261f <+319>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002623 <+323>: addq   $0x8, %rax
    0x100002627 <+327>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10000262b <+331>: testb  $0x1, 0x28(%rdi)
    0x10000262f <+335>: movq   %rax, -0xb0(%rbp)
    0x100002636 <+342>: jne    0x100002647               ; <+359> at main.swift:18
    0x100002638 <+344>: movq   -0xb0(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000263f <+351>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100002642 <+354>: callq  0x100002960               ; __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 at main.swift
    0x100002647 <+359>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rax
    0x10000264b <+363>: addq   $0x30, %rax
    0x10000264f <+367>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100002653 <+371>: testb  $0x1, 0x38(%rcx)
    0x100002657 <+375>: movq   %rax, -0xb8(%rbp)
    0x10000265e <+382>: jne    0x10000266f               ; <+399> at main.swift:18
    0x100002660 <+384>: movq   -0xb8(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002667 <+391>: movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x10000266a <+394>: callq  0x100001b40               ; outlined copy of Swift._VariantDictionaryBuffer with unmangled suffix ".1"
    0x10000266f <+399>: addq   $0xb8, %rsp
    0x100002676 <+406>: popq   %r13
    0x100002678 <+408>: popq   %rbp
    0x100002679 <+409>: retq
```

Uh oh! This line only showed up the second time:

```
0x10000256d <+141>: callq  0x10029cfe0               ; Swift.Optional._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> Swift.AnyObject
```

So, what it looks like is that when the compiler sees that you're casting an `AnyObject`, it thinks "Ooh, it's a class; it might be some Objective-C thing. Better bridge it to be sure," whereas if it sees an `Any`, it just goes "Herp derp, is this thing a `MyError`? No, it's `_SwiftValue`. Welp, guess that's that!" Aren't you glad the Swift team decided to have the `as?` keyword do two completely different things depending on context?

Comment: So all non-objects (i.e. value types like Int, struct, enum, etc.) are wrapped in an object so they can be send via a `Notification`? This is a really sad black magic. Thanks for the fix, but I am still hesitating to use it instead of `class` because one can forget about the cast to `AnyObject`. BTW it should probably be optional cast `... as? AnyObject...` instead of `...as AnyObject...`.

Comment: Oh, you don't know the beginning of how much black magic there is in the Swift<->Objective-C bridge.

Comment: Edited with my interpretation of what I *think* is going on.

Comment: Looks like we should be glad that Swift works at all :'D

Comment: The odd thing is that with certain value types, this'll work fine. For example, if you pass an `Int` as the notification's object and then try to cast that back to an `Int`, kablam, no problem. With numeric types, of course, the bridged type is `NSNumber`, not `_SwiftValue`, which might have something to do with it, I dunno.

Comment: There was a proposal on swift-evolution last year to get rid of a lot of the bridging magic in favor of more explicit casts, thus making `as?` behave predictably and consistently instead of trying to pretend you're not interacting with a completely different language, but sadly it was not accepted: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0083-remove-bridging-from-dynamic-casts.md

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to use `as? AnyObject` either, because `AnyObject` is itself magical. If you cast `nil` to `AnyObject`, it just gets wrapped in an `NSNull`. Isn't technology wonderful?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka It's not intentional behaviour; it's a bug with the Swift runtime. Casting from a `_SwiftValue` statically typed as `Any` to a protocol type *should* also check the bridged type for protocol conformance. Hopefully it gets fixed soon as I can imagine it can be a horribly subtle source of bugs for developers.

Comment: @Hamish I dunno, it's not nearly as great a source of subtle bugs as, say, [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5810), and that made it into the GM seed. :-/ Gonna be fun times on the SO Swift tag once that ships. Yes, I'm feeling a bit cranky.

Comment: Got a good laugh out of that, thanks.